# How can I check whether the column already has value?

Tags: java, android, cursor

How can I check whether the column already has value? Can use cursor to find?

I have two tables, one is table `info` and another is table `workDetails`

Table Info: `ID(PK), Name, Weather, Date, Status, TimeIn_Info, TimeOut_Info`

Table WorkDetails: `ID(PK),Project,WorkDescription,Per,TimeIn,TimeOut // 4 row`

There are 4 row in my WorkDetails and I only want the row which has value only will be inserted. And for the `TimeOut_Info`, it will get from `TimeOut`which is in table `WorkDetails`. If row 4 is empty, it will goes for row 3. If there exits a `TimeOut` value in row 3, it will insert into table Info and will not look for row 2 and row 1....

```
 public void checkRow2(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
       if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(a)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(b)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(c)) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(d))) {
          // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Doss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Row 2 is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return;

       }else if ((a != null && a.trim().length() > 0) && ((TextUtils.isEmpty(b)) && (c != null && c.trim().length() > 0) && (d != null && 

d.trim().length() > 0))) {
               WD.insertWorkDetails(a2, a, b, c, d);
               Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT TimeOut_Info FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO + " WHERE " +
                       MyDatabaseHelper.TimeOut_Info + "= '" + d + "'", null);
 if (mCursor == null) {
               database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
               ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
               values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.TimeOut_Info, d);
               database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO, null, values);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Per2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```

The coding `else-if` path  I attached doesn't work although it already meet the  condition. I wonder is it the way to check whether the selected column already has a value?

```
 Cursor cur = databaseb.rawQuery("SELECT COlumn COUNT(*) FROM +MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_INFO+ ", null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0){
            //do nothing everything's as it should be
        }
        else{
//
}
```

I have tried another method, but still no luck :(

Comment: By row 4, do you mean a row with ID=4 or the 4th row according to some unspecified sort order? Is the table only 4 rows long or is this a subset according to some unspecified criteria? Should new record be inserted with all null values except for `TimeOut_Info` every time the code is executed?

Comment: The table has 4 row.. New record include the TimeOut will be inserted as table workdetails as well.  For the TimeOut_info value, it is get from TimeOut... If row 3 has value TimeOut, the value will be inserted into table info.. Otherwise it will goes to another function which is row 2 and 1..

Comment: It only contains one row in table info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit difficult to figure out what you are trying to do, but if you for example have a `User` table, keyed by `UserId`, with an optional (nullable) `UserDescription`, and you want to check if a particular user has a description, the *SQL* to do so can be one of the following:

```sql
-- Return non-null value if user has description, null if not, or no record if user not found
SELECT UserDescription
  FROM User
 WHERE UserId = ?

-- Return 1 if user has description, 0 if not, or no record if user not found
SELECT CASE WHEN UserDescription IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HasDescription
  FROM User
 WHERE UserId = ?

-- Return 1 if user has description, or no record if not or if user not found
SELECT 1
  FROM User
 WHERE UserId = ?
   AND UserDescription IS NOT NULL

-- Return 1 if user has description, or 0 if not or if user not found
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM User
 WHERE UserId = ?
   AND UserDescription IS NOT NULL
```

There are more ways to do it.

Comment: The program will check whether the specific column is null or not. If it is null then only it will insert value d.

Comment: @Hoo Insert or update? Update which record? Or is this a single-row, single-column table? Your question is sorely lacking detail to understand your circumstance, though it does include a lot of other useless info.